# The Curious case of Android Context

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-sqlite, android-context

I have been into Android programming for quite some time now but I must admit **I have never understood Context**. I have always tried to make the Context situations just work as in the case of Toast, Databases, Views...etc.

*So I know what Context is but don't understand it.*

And before you start marking this as a duplicate please know that I have gone through the Web and Stack Overflow itself for all possible explanations for this topic and I (and a lot more) cant make out the meaning of statements like

"...**its the context of current state of the application/object.**"
"...**call it to get information regarding another part of your program**"
"...**A Context is a handle to the system**"

Now for all the enlightened souls out there, I'll put in the in the most straight forward manner

> What is Context in Android?

More importantly, when answering this could you please make me understand as to:

1. What exactly the Context object is **made up** of ? As in the values or key Value Pairs if any !
2. Is there a way of **dismantling** a Context Object(or a object in general ?)
3. How is the Context object used by its most popular recipients: *Toast, Databases, Views, Receivers, Intents* ?
4. How would the Context objects **differ** in case of *Activity Context, getApplicationContext(), getBaseContext().*

Comment: Your question requires lot of time and effort to answer fully. I doubt that anyone will spend the time. A good starting place is here where you can see the list of variables that a `Context` holds: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java?av=h#ContextImpl

Comment: Context is your parent, your father...
You need the context for another classes to get resources, inflaters and another classes.